# My cooldown decorator isn't functioning properly, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-decorators

So I attempted to make my own decorator, very similar to the built-in cooldown decorator provided to us within the discord.py module, except I'm trying to make it work on regular functions (e.g. non "@client.command async def myCommand()" functions) that it doesn't cover.

I have a function that says "hello" back to a user when they say "hello", but I don't want them spamming it over and over and causing the bot to spam it as well. This is what I have currently:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        try: 
            await sayHello(message)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

helloCooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1.0, 20.0, BucketType.user)
async def sayHello(message):

    bucket = helloCooldown.get_bucket(message)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    if retry_after:
        return # exits function if on cooldown / is rate limited

    author = message.author
    channel = message.channel

    await channel.send(f"Hello, {author.name}")
```

The decorator I created takes the rate, per, and type (similar to the built-in one) thats placed over a non-command function:

```py
def myCooldown(rate, per, type):

    def outer(func):

        def inner(*args):

            cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(rate, per, type)

            bucket = cd.get_bucket(args[0]) # get 'message' argument from the original function

            retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
            if retry_after:
                return # exit out if its on cooldown/ rate limited
            else:
                return func # executes function if not on cooldown

        return inner

    return outer

@myCooldown(1.0, 20.0, BucketType.user)
async def sayHello(message):
    # say hello
```

The expected behavior is that it stays on cooldown for 20 seconds before saying "hello" again, if it's called. However, I get the error message "`Object function cant be used in 'await' expression`". How can I fix my decorator to work the way I'm intending it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to `await sayHello(message)`, first `sayHello(message)` is executed (which is really `inner(message)`), which returns `func`.

Your program tries to `await func`, which doesn't really make sense, so it throws an error.

You need to change `inner` so it returns an await-able object.  This means that it can't return `None`, so you should raise an error instead.

```
from discord import DiscordException

class FunctionOnCooldown(DiscordException):
    pass 

def myCooldown(rate, per, type):
    def outer(func):
        cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(rate, per, type)
        def inner(message, *args, **kwargs):
            bucket = cd.get_bucket(message) 

            retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
            if retry_after:
                raise FunctionOnCooldown
            else:
                return func(*args, **kwargs) # executes function if not on cooldown

        return inner

    return outer
```

Comment: I tried the above code and although it doesn't give an error, it doesn't put the function on cooldown. It still allows me and others to use it over and over. Come to think of it, its actually creating a whole new instance every time the decorator is used. Is there a way to create that instance and then check if it currently exists?

Comment: You can probably just move the `cd = ...` line outside of `inner`

Comment: Everything works! Many thanks for the assistance, I thought it would have been much harder lol

Comment: An alternative solution might be to make `inner` an async function, which does `return await func(*args)`. I think this would let you continue to return `None` in the case where you're blocked.